# how to customize jquery.formset.js django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, formset

i have created a form with `inlineformset_factory` with `jquery.formset.js` library for increasing rows , but i cant change default position of add and delete buttons , this is the library i have used [https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.formset/1.2.2/jquery.formset.js[1](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.formset/1.2.2/jquery.formset.js)

and this is the template's view [image]

and this is the script

```js
<script>
    $(function(){

        $('.tb1 tr:last').formset({
            prefix:'{{items.prefix}}',
            addText:'add',
            addCssClass:'add-row btn btn-info',
            deleteText:'delete',
            deleteCssClass:' delete-row btn btn-danger',
            added:function($row){
                $('.item').select2();
            }
        })  
        $(".item").select2();

    })
</script>
```

i want to push delete and add buttons both in one row

```html
<tr style="background-color: #5dbcd3;color: #ffffff;">
   <th>
     <div>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add">+</button>
      </div>
   </th>
   <th class="btn btn-danger" id="del">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">-</button>
   </th>
</tr>
```

is there a way to customize it ? i know i have to change some codes in the jquery.formset.js library , i dont know how to do it ! i tried alot ..

thanks for answering ..

Answer (score 0):

Use the default button that comes with the library.

And locate them in an extra field at the bottom of the table, since if you're using Django Admin when you send a POST request you are resending all the document and extracting what matches your needs.

Hope this comment helps even when there's no snippet, if not, write me back, I wanted to answer you ASAP.